# problem with autocomplete script

Tags: php

I have a autocomplete script in PHP but problem with the code is I can't select suggested Values using my keyboard else script is running well with mouse but I wanna fix keyboard selection problem... Pasting a part of code with this....

```
$country = str_ireplace($str,"<b>".$str."</b>",($row['name']));
echo "<tr id=\"word".$row['id']."\" onmouseover=\"highlight(1,'".$row['id']."');\" onmouseout=\"highlight(0,'".$row['id']."');\" onClick=\"display('".$row['name']."');\" >\n<td>".$country."</td>\n</tr>\n";
```

even is selected onkeyup function.

Comment: Please help with this script instead of giving links to other...

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of things, you should not try to re-invent the wheel<sup>1</sup> -- instead, you should use some existing *(used a lot, well tested, ...)* solution !

For an example, take a look at [jQuery's Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) -- there's a demo at the bottom of the page ; you can see that the keyboard works, on this one.

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>and either fail, or spend hours or day debugging...</sub>

Comment: I am not satisfied this.... because its providing implmentation using array n I wanna implement using DB sooo. N I am also new to this...